# How to interpret ASCII command codes in a stream before saving to a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm saving standard output stream to a file:

```
mvn test > output.txt
```

Before saving to a file I want to properly process ASCII command codes (especially `0x0D` and `0x08`) in order to make file more readable.

For example, in `line 1\rline 2\n` the `\r` should move the position to the start of the same line, so that overwriting from there results in `line 2\n` being saved.  Similarly `barbar\rfoo\n` should end as `foobar\n`.

Do such tools exist in Linux or do I have to write something from scratch?

Comment: U+000D isn't a command code. It's a new line. More specifically, a carriage return.

Comment: Exactly, that's why it has to be **pre** processed like a carriage return

Comment: read the fine manual: man sed, something along `sed 's/.*\r//'`

Comment: read the file in less, which will translate nasty ascii command codes (Maven shouldn't be outputting them anyway, unless you have an errant plugin)

Comment: I would like to remind you that on some systems l, U+000D (`\r`) _is_ a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pipe your output through `col -b`. It doesn't understand all possible control characters and escape sequences, but at least it knows carriage return and backspace. It outputs what would be visible at the end if its input had been printed to a terminal. (An infinitely tall terminal with destructive backspace)

Comment: `echo 'line 1\rline 2\n' | col -b` doesn't seem to insert any new lines?  At least on OSX.

Comment: I don't need to insert a new line, I need to interpret ASCII codes as intended. `\r` is NOT a new line, but a carriage return

Comment: I spoke loosely.  At least on OSX, the output of `echo 'line 1\rline 2\n' | col -b` is `line 1\rline 2\n` (literal backslashes, `r`s and `n`s.)

Comment: ..and I just confirmed the same behavior on Ubuntu 12.04.  What do you mean precisely by 'interpret'?

Comment: @phs there is a shell option for that. `shopt -s xpg_echo` or `shopt -u xpg_echo`.

Comment: `xpg_echo` appears to only control how the `echo` built-in by default treats deals with escape sequences (such as these.)  Which of `mvn` or `col` is using it, or `echo`?

Comment: Put it another way, with `xpg_echo` set the echo doesn't need the `col -b` at all.

Comment: @phs `xpg_echo` isn't relevant to the original question, which didn't mention `echo` at all. I'm just trying to explain to you that your test command doesn't match what the question was asking, and if you wanted to make it match, you should set the `xpg_echo` option, *then* run `echo 'line1\rline2\n' | col -b`

Comment: Here's where I think we get to the confusion.  I don't believe `mvn` is emitting `0x0D` or `0x08` bytes at all, but rather two-byte escape sequences.  OP is mistaking the situation as his terminal escaping the invisibles.  He needs something to manually apply character escapes.

Comment: @phs I interpreted the question the opposite way, and since my answer got accepted maybe you should try looking at it that way. I think it said "`mvn` outputs some stuff with carriage returns in it", using `\r` not because C escape sequences are actually involved, but because they're a convenient way for programmers to talk to each other about control characters. Maybe I was at an advantage because I don't know what `mvn` is and was able to focus on the important stuff

Comment: It's a java build tool, and as such usually strongly prefers to pretend things like terminals don't exist.  On a third reading, I agree with you both (though OP certainly could clarified with a better example.)